# Why doesn't gradient background work in firefox if the font is bold and smaller

Tags: html, css

I have a div that enforces a specific font size and weight and a text node inside that uses a gradient background (many small dots) for hightlighting

In firefox (66.0.3 Ubuntu) the background is only visible if I remove one of the two font declarations

```
font-size: 0.8em;
font-weight: bold;
```

Normal font: [image: Normal font]
Bold font: [image: Bold font]

Here is my complete code

```css
.title {
    /* these two influence the gradient background */
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
  
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.title span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.highlighted-area {
    background: linear-gradient( 90deg, lightgrey 3px, transparent 1% ) center
              , linear-gradient(        lightgrey 3px, transparent 1% ) center
              , white;
    background-size: 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;">
    <span class="highlighted-area">Title</span>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYyYOw

Comment: Works fine here (66.0.3 in Windows).

Comment: What version of firefox do you use?

Comment: @xmastertje 66.0.3 64bit on Ubuntu

Comment: I guess it's a Firefox bug on that version or system.

Comment: @Hachi i read `-moz-linear-gradient` this on a website. I didn't test it but maybe it works for you.

Comment: @xmastertje thanks. -moz-linear-gradient doesn't change anything for me

Comment: You may want to open an issue on Mozilla's bugzilla and let them know about it, while including as much information as you can about your system.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1551807